# Clipping stat_density2d plot by polygon in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, geospatial

I am plotting 2d density map of github profiles in continental US. Dataframe looks like this:

```
> head(f)
    login id        location      lat       long
1 defunkt  2   San Francisco 37.78300 -122.41700
2 pjhyett  3   San Francisco 37.78300 -122.41700
3  wycats  4   San Francisco 37.78300 -122.41700
4    ivey  6 Bay Minette, AL 30.88333  -87.77694
5 evanphx  7 Los Angeles, CA 34.05000 -118.25000
6 vanpelt 17   San Francisco 37.78300 -122.41700
```

So far I came up with this code:

```
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
library(ggplot2)

all_states <- map_data("state")
p <- ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon( data=all_states, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group),color="grey60", fill="white") +
  stat_density2d(data=f, aes(x=long, y=lat,fill = ..level..),geom='polygon') +
  theme(
    axis.line = element_blank(), 
    axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
    axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank()
  ) 

print(p)
```

This code produces following image:

[image: github density map usa bad graph]

How to clip density areas that are over US border?

Comment: you could draw a polygon in white above the oceans and Canada.